# How do I affix visual magic effects and items in-game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have some mods that I've downloaded and I've noticed that they were able to input plates and vases that can't be moved or stolen. They are just fixed in place and even models of dragons and werewolves they would use to display as mounts to decorate certain places.

I also wondered how they get certain visual magic effects (like the effects you see when you scroll to the magic menu abilities and choose a magic ability). Yet they would have those same effects mounted on something for decoration.

How can I obtain these things to create a certain look in my houses or in Castle Volkihar? Can these things be console commanded or do I have to go to the Creation Kit to put them in the world?

Comment: Hi Zadekiel, your question is off-topic on Arqade. You can try asking it on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), however. Good luck!

Comment: @Joachim  While this may be on-topic on Game Development SE, it doesn't sound like OP wants to develop a mod, but just asking if he might need to use the Creation Kit to do what he's asking about. I believe this is on-topic here.

Comment: @galacticninja The problem is, in my opinion, that going into details about it in the answer of how to do so in the CK, which is the only option (I *think*), would be off-topic. A simple "yes, you are going to need the CK" would be a subpar answer.

Comment: @Joachim I'm thinking console commands might work too, or maybe an existing mod that can do this.

Comment: @galacticninja I don't think the effects mentioned have meshes, though. Lights and some types of smoke - if I'm not mistaken - do, and can be manipulated in-game, using a mod like Jaxonz Positioner.

Comment: If console commands is the key, how do I get the ID ref for those effects to fix them where I want?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, I *think* the particular effect you see in the menus does not have a mesh, so it can't be selected using the console, hence neither by mods, meaning the mod authors used the Creation Kit to place the effects.

That is, unless you mean the 'icons' of spells and active effects, like this one:

[image: Example of spell effect]

In that case, since they do have meshes, you can use the same mod to position them.

**To spawn them, you can use the mod [AddItemMenu](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/64905/?)**: it allows you to pick any item referenced in your current game (i.e. including any loaded mods) through a convenient menu:

[image: Select an .esm or .esp file to select any item referenced in it]

---

For most items, I suggest using a mod like [Jaxonz Positioner](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52583) or [Placeable Statics](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/25068/?)*. Using it, you can manipulate (almost?) everything with a three-dimensional model (using a .nif file), including lights. As per the mod's description:

> Move practically any object in the game, including grabbable objects,
>   furniture, containers, and statics.

**You can choose to have them be immovable after manipulation**, or still be susceptible to the game's physics engine.

<sup>* [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/5xf7ff/jaxonz_positioner_or_placeable_statics/) is a comparison between multiple mods with the same functionality.</sup>

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/64905/?

Comment: YOU have been awesome!!!
I have Jaxons Positioner and with that mod, I was able to copy magic effects that other modders had and put them where I wanted.
However, if I ever uninstalled their mod I would also lose the effect I copied from their mod.
So I wanted to do it myself to always have it.
Two questions I have for you now.
Where in the Creation Kit do I find the effects?
How do I also place items that can't be moved to decorate like platers, cups, plates, potions, etc?
Thanks for your most helpful reply!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Instead of answering you here, how about you ask a new question? I'd love to answer it thoroughly.